# How to add custom section in app. config file

Tags: c#

This is my `app.config` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <configSections>
      <section name="customSettings" type="ConsoleApplication6.Class1,ConsoleApplication6 "/>
   </configSections>

   <customSettings>
      <name>mala</name> 
   </customSettings>
</configuration>
```

C# code, implemented create method `IConfigurationSectionHandler` interface

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml;


public class Class1
{
    public string name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name=value;}
    }

    public class configH : IConfigurationSectionHandler
    {
        public configH() { }

        public object Create(object parent, object configContext, System.Xml.XmlNode section)
        {
            Class1 cl = new Class1();
            cl.name = section.SelectSingleNode("name").InnerText;
            return cl;
        }
    }
}
```

Main program

```
namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Class1 settings = (Class1)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("customSettings");
        Console.WriteLine(settings.name);
    }
}
```

but I'm getting an error when running it

> An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for customSettings: Type 'ConsoleApplication6.Class1' does not inherit from 'System.Configuration.IConfigurationSectionHandler'

I'm not sure about the type attribute in section tag in `app.config` file. I used like `TYPE=classname,namespacename`

Answer (score 0):

Use this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306572/app-config-custom-section-not-working):

```
<configSection>
    <section
            name="YOUR_CLASS_NAME_HERE"
            type="YOUR.NAMESPACE.CLASSNAME, YOUR.NAMESPACE, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=PUBLIC_TOKEN_ID_FROM_ASSEMBLY"
            allowLocation="true"
            allowDefinition="Everywhere"
          />
</configSection>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.but i find difficult to get the public token id. i tried in Visual Studio toos-> external tools. but theres not thing like "Get &PublicKeyToken"